# <pre> Tag overflows css3 columns

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I can't seem to figure out how to hide, clip or truncate content which overflows a CSS3 column. If I happen to have a code snippet in a `<pre>` tag in my first column, it crosses over into my second column making text illegible.

For this particular use I'd be happy clipping the text, adding ellipses, or pretty much anything that will make the content not run over into the other columns.

In the JSFiddle below I have styled the `<pre>` content in blue so you can see it easily. You can reproduce it with the code below if you wish.

http://jsfiddle.net/a4vvcLhv/

```
.columns {
        -moz-column-width: 150px;
        -webkit-column-width: 150px;
        column-width: 150px;
        overflow: hidden;
}

<div class='columns'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas orci a sem vulputate, nec tincidunt urna aliquet. 

<pre>print "Hello world, how are you doing today? Is this getting cut off yet?</pre>

    Proin consequat velit quis iaculis vulputate. Vestibulum iaculis lorem nec commodo commodo. 

 Etiam sed orci nibh. Quisque rutrum hendrerit lacinia. Praesent quis mattis massa, eget iaculis dui. Praesent faucibus venenatis varius. Vestibulum commodo porta turpis, placerat interdum metus ultricies ut. Vivamus laoreet suscipit purus placerat pulvinar. Etiam tellus nunc
</div>
```

It's not just the `<pre>` tag, though that was the first thing I came across and the example I gave. Images cause the same issue. I have updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/a4vvcLhv/1/) with an image to show it.

What I'm seeing looks like it might be by design, unfortunately. [W3.org - Overflow inside multicol elements](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/#overflow-inside-multicol-elements).

---

More info: I was/am experiencing this in Firefox. Chrome clips things as I expected/wanted them to be displayed, but I think that Firefox's way is correct per the W3.org link above.

I can get close to the desired behavior in Firefox by adding the following:

```
.articlewords {
    -moz-column-width: 220px;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px inset #333;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-break-after: right;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;

    -webkit-column-width: 220px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px inset #333;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-break-after: right;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;

    column-width: 220px;
    column-rule: 1px inset #333;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-break-after: right;
    column-fill: auto;

    height: 100%;
}


.articlewords * { 
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
```

The `.articlewords *` stanza has the side-effect of shrinking images to fit into the column instead of clipping them. It'll probably be good enough for my needs, but it's not the behavior I would like (strict clipping at the column brea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `<pre>` tag displays the contents inside it **pre-formatted**.

Instead of the `<pre>`, you can use this:

`<div style='font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;'> text here </div>`

You can tweak the formatting to make it display like you desire: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6u3tyuw/).

**Edit:** In case you want to stick with the `<pre>` tags, then you can **pre-wrap the white-space**. You just have to update your css for the `<pre>` tag to include:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgurmz86).

Comment: In my actual situation I'm reading content from a couple or RSS feeds so I don't have control over the tags, and it turns out that other things like images cause the problem too.

Comment: Before downvoting my answer, don't you think this was an important detail to have mentioned in the question?

Comment: I didn't down vote it, and at the time I didn't know that other tags were causing problems.

Comment: oh ok. I hope your problem is solved. How did you decide to go about it?

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet. Chrome actually displays things as I want them, but the w3 docs seem to say that Firefox is displaying it correctly (but not how I want it to).

Comment: Checkout this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgurmz86/ . You can pre-wrap the white-space. You just have to update your css for the <pre> tag. Hope it works!

Comment: not for nothing @stuporglue, you can add the css property using javascript after the DOM is laoded, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `white-space: pre-wrap;` style to the `<pre>` tag for word wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
pre{
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

the text will be truncated and the dottes will be shown

[the example](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vvcLhv/2/)

Or if you want to show the content of pre, add `white-space: pre-wrap;`

[example with pre-wrap](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vvcLhv/4/)